# Reference a variable value with another variable

Tags: javascript

I want to store some number values as variables and then reference them by combining other variables together but I can't insert the values into inner html, only the variable names

```
var a1 = 2.00;
var a2 = 4.00;
var a3 = 6.00;
var input1 = $("#one").val(); //gives a
var input2 = $("#two").val(); //gives 1, 2 or 3

var code = input1 + input2; //combines input 1 and input 2 to give eg a2
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = code;
```

Currently I can output eg "a1", "a2", "a3" but not the values I've assigned to those variables. I think I need to change the syntax on ".innerhtml = code;" but I'm not sure how. I've also tried setting the a variables as objects with "price" but still have the same issue

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry I want the output to be 2.00 or 4.00 or 6.00 (essentially a price value)

Answer (score 0):

Store codes in object instead of separate variable. Then use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to construct object key from variables:

```
var codes = {
  a1: 2.00,
  a2: 4.00,
  a3: 6.00
}

var input1 = $("#one").val(); // gives a
var input2 = $("#two").val(); // gives 1, 2 or 3

var code = codes[input1 + input2]; // combines input 1 and input 2 to give eg a2
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a object to store the values, the you can use [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access property from the object `obj`

```js
var obj = {
  a1: 2.00,
  a2: 4.00,
  a3: 6.00
}

var input1 = 'a';
var input2 = '2';

var code = obj[input1 + input2]; //combines input 1 and input 2 to give eg a2
console.log(code);
```