# Reference a Javascript variable name in InnerHTML by concatenating string and integer

Tags: javascript, concatenation, innerhtml

I have the below Javascript function where I was hoping to dynamically reference a variable from an InnerHTML by concatenating a string with an integer, but this does not seem to work (a string is returned):

```
function TestFunction() {
    var activity_1 = "Hello World";
    var i = 1;
    var x = 'activity_' + i;
    document.getElementById("myTest").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var obj = {
  "activity_1 ": "Hello World"
};

var x= 'activity_' + i;
document.getElementById("myTest").innerHTML = obj [x];`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103509/reference-a-variable-value-with-another-variable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check this code and let me know is it working or not.

```js
function TestFunction() {
    var obj = {activity_1:"Hello World"};
    var i = 1;
    var x = "activity_" + i;

    document.getElementById("myTest").innerHTML = obj[x];
}

TestFunction();
```

```html
<div id="myTest"></div>
```

Comment: That's perfect.  Thanks for your guidance on this everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use an object literal to store multiple references to variables

```js
var test = {
  activity_1: "Hello World",
  i: 1
}

var x = test.activity_1+' '+ test.i;

document.getElementById("xTest").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<div id='xTest'></div>
```